# Jagged Array keeps changing all arrays

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net

```
      For x = 0 To n - 1

        str = Lines(x, 0)
        For g = 1 To 29
            str = (str + Lines(x, g))
        Next
        For y = 0 To 899
            patternarr(y) = CInt(Mid(str, y + 1, 1))


        Next
        Pattern(x) = patternarr

    Next
```

Pattern() is a Jagged integer Array.
Patternarr is an integer array.
This is part of a loop with Patternarr changing every loop and x increasing by 1.
The issue is, for some reason, everyloop, all the arrays in Patten() get replaced by patternarr.

Comment: Include a little more code; this isn't enough to see what's happening.

Comment: That tiny snippet doesnt tell us much.  Most likely you stored the same array over and over in the jagged array.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are reference types, so each element of `Pattern` holds a reference to the same `patternarr`.  In other words, `Pattern(x) = patternarr` does NOT make a copy of `patternarr`, it just points to the existing `patternarr`.  As a result, any time you make a change to `patternarr`, that change is reflected in every element of `Pattern`.  If you want each element of `Pattern` to be independent, you must make copies of `patternarr` as you save them in `Pattern`:

```
Pattern(x) = patternarr.Clone()
```